# using c# how to Print Line number of randomly selected line from parsed file

Tags: c#, parsing, random, printing, line-numbers

this is a snippet of my program that catches an incomplete line in the file, however I need it to tell me the line number that it pulled so I can do error handling better.

```
var testLines = File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        Item.ran = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
        var randomTestLine = testLines[Item.ran.Next(testLines.Length)];
        if (randomTestLine.StartsWith("*"))
        {
            pick++;
            count = pick.ToString();
            Picks.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
            Picks.Text = count;
            ItemGenerated.Text = ( !!something needs to go here!! + "Incomplete Item Entry\n" + randomTestLine);
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: What language is this?  Please edit the question to include the appropriate language tag(s).

Comment: I totally spaced out and forgot that, there fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var lineNumber = Item.ran.Next(testLines.Length);
var randomTestLine = testLines[lineNumber];
```

...

```
ItemGenerated.Text = ( lineNumber + "Incomplete Item Entry\n" + randomTestLine);
```

?

Comment: that worked perfectly thank you. I needed to add ItemGenerated.Text = ( (lineNumber + 1) + "Incomplete Item Entry\n" + randomTestLine); so the count would match properly.